# sqoop Import job failed

Tags: hive, sqoop

when i try to import my table using this command sqoop:

```
sqoop import --verbose --driver $DRIVER_CLASS --connect $URL --username $LOGIN --password $PASSWORD \
--table $TABLE --hive-import --hive-table $TABLE_HIVE \
--hive-partition-key "to_porcess_ts" --hive-partition-value "$current_date" --split-by $DST_SPLIT_COLUMN --num-mappers 4 \
--compress \
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
```

I initialized all my avariables in my shell script; for example `current_date=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)` .

But i got this error:

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Import job failed!
```

And i did not understand the reason.

Comment: Can you post full log

Comment: what is the driver class name ? And is that jar is in the classpath?

Comment: this is the last lines of my log file `2018-06-05 19:57:38,180 INFO [Thread-471] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 37421
2018-06-05 19:57:38,180 INFO [IPC Server listener on 37421] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 37421
2018-06-05 19:57:38,180 INFO [IPC Server Responder] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2018-06-05 19:57:38,183 INFO [Thread-471] org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:0`

Comment: Could you please set verbose(set -vx) in shell script  after Shebang... It will print the command with replaced variables, so that we can get to know if the variables are getting passed correctly